# Contractible subcomplex containing 1-skeleton?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes, cw-complexes

Question: If $X$ is a simplicial complex that's simply connected and $2$-dimensional, does there always exist a contractible subcomplex $Y$ satisfying $X^{(1)} \subseteq Y$?

The statement is true "down a dimension": If $X$ is connected and $1$-dimensional, then there exists a contractible subcomplex $Y$ satisfying $X^{(0)} \subseteq Y$, namely you can use a spanning tree. So, one could think of the desired $Y$ in the original problem as a $2$-dimensional analog of a spanning tree, with contractibility being the key desired property.

It seems there is a higher dimensional analog of "spanning tree" in the literature, at least for finite complexes, e.g., Definition 3.1 of [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-11/S0002-9947-09-04898-3/S0002-9947-09-04898-3.pdf). Note that Proposition 3.7 of that paper implies that (finite) simply connected $2$-complexes indeed have these sorts of $2$-dimensional "spanning trees". But these are not necessarily contractible, they're more of a homological analog of trees.

Comment: You would need your complex to be homotopy equivalenct to a wedge of 2-spheres since contracting Y would give a sphere for each triangle not in Y.  I don't know if that is sufficient

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg That's true, but it turns out every simply connected $2$-complex is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of 2-spheres! (According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747597/a-characterization-of-wedges-of-1-spheres-and-2-spheres this is "well known", but I guess I don't actually know a proof.)

Comment: Ok.  I didn't know that.

Comment: Perhaps the proof of this fact gives this contractible spanning complex?

Comment: Can you just order the 2-cells and mark which don't increase the second Betti number when attached, and then the subcomplex is given by attaching these cells to the 1-skeleton?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg That would be great, though I can't actually find a proof anywhere. I suspect the proof might involve showing some map from a wedge of spheres to $X$ induces an isomorphism in all $\pi_k$ and appealing to Whitehead, which wouldn't be very constructive. On the other hand thanks to the Whitehead group of the trivial group being trivial, we know the homotopy equivalence is WLOG a simple homotopy equivalence. So that's more specific to the cell structure and might be helpful.

Comment: @ConnorMalin That's a good idea. I have two worries: 1) I worry that since the designation "doesn't create any 2-homology" for a simplex is dependent on the choice of order, when we effectively change the order to start with all those 2-simplices it might also change their designations. And, 2) I worry that it's hard to control whether the resulting subcomplex is simply connected; I would believe that you can maybe ensure it has trivial $H_1$, but trivial $\pi_1$ it's hard to say. (Neither of these worries is grounded in anything concrete, just a feeling.)

Comment: FWIW, the proof that it is a wedge of spheres is just that simply connected Moore spaces are unique up to homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Aha, the "Moore space" terminology makes it much easier to find a proof, e.g., Example 4.34 in Hatcher does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is no.

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology there is an example of an acyclic 2-dimensional complex with one 0-cell, two 1-cells and two 2-cells (Example 2.38). You start with a wedge of two circles, labeled $a$ and $b$, and attach two 2-dimensional cells by the words $a^5b^{-3}$ and $b^2(ab)^{-2}$. One can easily check that it is acyclic. The fundamental group has the presentation $<a, b\mid a^5b^{-3}, b^2(ab)^{-2}>$, and one can show that it is not trivial. Now form a new complex $X$ by attaching one more $2$-dimensional cell, along $b$. The fundamental group of $X$ is easily seen to be trivial. But no proper subcomplex of $X$ containing the $1$-skeleton is simply-connected, let alone contractible.

To make this example into a simplicial complex, choose a triangulation of $X$. This can be done because all the attaching maps are nice piece-wise linear maps. I believe it is still true that no simplicial subcomplex of $X$ that contains the $1$-skeleton is contractible. Removing a two-cell from the triangulation of $X$ is like punching a hole in a two cell in the original CW structure on $X$. We already know that punching a single hole in some of the cells does not make a contractible complex, and punching additional holes only makes the fundamental group bigger.

Comment: Aha, excellent! I think this works. Is it obvious that $X$ itself is not contractible? That's the only thing I don't see right away.

Comment: $X$ has Euler characteristic 2, so not contractible.

Comment: Perfect! And actually, I think this same sort of idea, of taking a presentation for the trivial group that becomes non-trivial upon removing any one defining relator, would work for an even simpler example, like the presentation 2-complex of $\langle a\mid a^2,a^3\rangle$.

Comment: Duh. Of course. Well spotted.